# Assign Delegated permission for System Assigned Managed Identity to Graph Api

Tags: graph, identity, managed

I am trying to setup Managed Identity (system assigned), to assign delegated permission (like Tasks.ReadWrite) and then to use it to call Graph Api.

I have identified object Id using following code:

```
$app = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true -Filter "AppId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'"
$role = $app.Oauth2Permissions | where-Object { $_.AdminConsentDisplayName -eq "Create, read, update, and delete user’s tasks and task lists" }
```

but when I run following command:

```
New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -Id $role.Id -ObjectId $miObjectID -PrincipalId $miObjectID -ResourceId $app.ObjectId
```

where $miObjectID is my managed identity Id, I am getting following error message:

```
New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment : Error occurred while executing NewServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Permission being assigned was not found on application
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to do the same. My understanding is, that this is not intended to be.

Typically, `user-delegated` permissions are supposed to be used interactively, involving user interaction, e.g. on a web-app accessing user resources on his behalf. If, like me, you're developing a backend service, this won't fly. For this scenario the supported way is to just use `application` permissions and be done with it.

However, imho application permissions are often too broad, granting access to ressources that are irrelevant. E.g. if your app needs to have access to one specific Sharepoint site, you have to authorize access for [*all*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#:%7E:text=Allows%20the%20app%20to%20read%20documents%20and%20list%20items%20in%20all%20site%20collections%20without%20a%20signed%20in%20user.) sites in your tenant. Application permission cannot be scoped.

Due to compliance reasons this is not acceptable. Especially if you work in a LOB org.

Still, I did find a workaround to have the best of both worlds, i.e. having really scoped permissions and have the ability to leverage these unattended in a backend service. But there is one caveat: I did not get it working with a managed identity I had to use a regular service principal. If that's a compromise you can accept, the following may be helpful to you.

- Dedicate a user principal for this scenario. Authorise that user as needed. Choose a password with max length, i.e. 256 chars. Enable MFA.
- Create an app/service principal in Azure AD, generate client/app credentials
- Create a demo web-app locally using [available templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code) and the MSAL lib. Have the above app request the required user-delegated permissions from the user
- Then, in the app code, use the [Resource-owner password credential, ROPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) flow to authenticate the app and assume the permissions from the user

```cs
    public class RessourceOwnerPasswordCredentialFlow
    {
        public static async Task<AccessToken> GetToken(HttpClient http, string credJson, Guid tenantId)
        {
            var ropc = credJson.Deserialize<GraphROPC>();
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dict.Add("grant_type", "password"); // ROPC
            dict.Add("username", ropc.User);
            dict.Add("password", ropc.Password);
            dict.Add("client_id", ropc.ClientId);
            dict.Add("client_secret", ropc.ClientSecret);
            dict.Add("scope", ".default");
            var url = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
            var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url) { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict) };
            var res = await http.SendAsync(req);
            var content = await res.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            var authResp = await content.DeserializeAsync<GraphAuthResponse>();
            return new AccessToken(authResp.access_token, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(authResp.expires_in));
        }
    }

    public class GraphROPC
    {
        public string User { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string ClientId { get; set; }
        public string ClientSecret { get; set; }
    }

    public class GraphAuthResponse
    {
        public string token_type { get; set; }
        public string scope { get; set; }
        public int expires_in { get; set; }
        public string access_token { get; set; }
    }
```

#### Note: Using the ROPC is [not recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc#:%7E:text=Microsoft%20recommends%20you%20do%20not%20use%20the%20ROPC%20flow) by Microsoft.

However, I have found most of the objections to be not applicable in *my* case.

- There is really no alternative to use delegated-permissions within a backend service app
- I do have absolute trust in the app, because it's developed by me
- The app does have to know the user credentials, these are stored in a KeyVault to which only the app has access (this time using MSI)
- Also, one could argue that using *two* sets of credentials, user credentials plus app credentials is superior to using *just* the client credentials one would use if working with (more excessive) application permissions.
- The ROPC doc says, that user accounts with MFA are [not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc#:%7E:text=If%20users%20need%20to%20use%20multi%2Dfactor%20authentication%20(MFA)%20to%20log%20in%20to%20the%20application%2C%20they%20will%20be%20blocked%20instead.). However, I can confirm it is possible to work-around this restriction if [conditional access policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/location-condition) are used. In our case the app has a fixed outbound public IP address which can be added  as a [trusted location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/location-condition#trusted-locations). In fact, if the ability to whitelist a trusted location from the MFA requirement were missing, this would have been a blocker for the above steps.